# How to run a system command from a django web application?

Tags: python, linux, django, celery

Does anyone knows of a proven and simple way of running a system command from a django application?

Maybe using celery? ...

From my research, it's a problematic task, since it involves permissions and insecure approaches to the problem. Am i right?

EDIT: Use case: delete some files on a remote machine.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, usually running a system command from a web application is risky thing to do. 
What is the use case that your looking at ?

Comment: Things to worry about as i can think of, how are you determining the file name (full path) of the file to be deleted. 
If your forced to use a file, i would suggest you to just move a file to temp folder, then have a cron job scheduled to delete the files.
Assuming that your web applications can access specified dir . 
You might also want to have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/storage/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach: in your Django web application, write a message to a queue (e.g., RabbitMQ) containing the information that you need. In a separate system, read the message from the queue and perform any file actions. You can indeed use Celery for setting up this system.